# React Native Router Flux - Gradually change the StatusBar color from one color to another when swiping through tabs

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've seen a lot of questions similar to mine, but they do not actually aim for what I am looking for.

I've seen that react native router flux has a way of gradually changing the tab bar icon colours when swiping from one screen to another, like in the bellow gif.

[image]

Could this be achieved the same way for the status bar? The closest way of doing this was using OnEnter, OnExit events, but they do have a delay since the events themselves trigger upon transition is finished.

If you need more explanations, I will provide them, since I really want to implement this feature in the app.

Cheers,
Birkan